when i use expo go SDK 51 it's error like this. how can i resolve?
enter image description hereiOS Bundling failed 10600ms node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js (1342 modules)
Unable to resolve "missing-asset-registry-path" from "assets/fonts/Kantumruy-Bold.ttf"
when i use expo go SDK 51 it's error like this. how can i resolve?
in app.json
expo:[ "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/**/*"
    ],] ```
i put this code 
and then i try to install expo-font
it still not work 

